# MinMaxSlider GUI for my game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking for a GUI element that has the functionality of the MinMaxSlider of the Unity Editor. But I would like to use this type of GUI in my game. The simple GUI.HorizontalSlider is not good enough. Where can I find such an element.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [these guys](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: would help to know why horizontal slider isn't "good" enough so that someone can point you in the direction of your needs.

Comment: The HorizontalSlider provides one slider that returns one value while with the MinMaxSlider you can change a range. The left part of the slider can change independently of the right part of the slider. Lets say you have a slider with "all of time" and you want to see the events that happened between 1234BC and 33AD. I would like to achieve something like that.

Comment: what about using an advanced GUI toolkit for Unity and then create a custom slider? Take a look at the Assets store, for example at NGUI... Otherwise, with the next Unity release there will be a [GUI editor integrated](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/28/overview-of-the-new-ui-system/), if you can wait for it...

Comment: well I did ask the question about a year ago ...